# Android camera permission request does not trigger request popup

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-permissions

I am using React Native and tying to give the app camera permissions for my Android app.

I'm using RN v0.59.9 and SDK 28.

With the code below, the app successfully requests permission to access contacts, but it does not request camera permissions, even though the code for the camera permission request is lifted *straight* from the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid)

What could be going wrong?

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

export const requestPermissions = () => {
  PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
    {
      'title': 'Contacts',
      'message': 'The app would like to view your contacts.'
    }
  )
  requestCameraPermission();
}

async function requestCameraPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        message:
          'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
          'so you can take awesome pictures.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('You can use the camera');
    } else {
      console.log('Camera permission denied');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}
```

## Update

If I remove the contacts permissions request like this:

```
export const requestPermissions = () => {
  // PermissionsAndroid.request(
  //   PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
  //   {
  //     'title': 'Contacts',
  //     'message': 'The app would like to view your contacts.'
  //   }
  // )
  requestCameraPermission();
}

function requestCameraPermission() {
  PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
    {
      title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
      message:
        'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
        'so you can take awesome pictures.',
      buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
      buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
      buttonPositive: 'OK',
    },
  );
}
```

The camera request works, so looks like I can't chain them like this?

Comment: Did you remember to add the `CAMERA` permission in the manifest? Btw, unless you're using the camera directly yourself, you don't actually need that permission. If you're starting another app to take a picture for you, there's no need for your app to ask for the `CAMERA` permission.

Comment: I hadn't done that as I don't think you need to if using `import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';`. You don't need to do it for contacts permissions. I just tried it and it didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I'm not too familiar with React Native. I'd just seen permissions present in the manifests posted on other React Native questions. Anyhoo, are you directly using the camera yourself? If not, you don't really need that permission, as long as it doesn't ultimately appear in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. yes I'll be using the camera directly in the app for video.

Comment: Cool. I think I see your problem, though. The permissions dialog doesn't block, so in your first example, it's trying to request the camera permission immediately after showing the dialog for contacts. IIRC, that'll cause the second request to immediately return an empty result, and you aren't seeing anything from that. As I mentioned, I'm not familiar with React Native, but I'd guess that if you do the `await` in the contacts block, too, it'll work. Otherwise, there should be a way for you to request both permissions at the same time (at least there is in native code).

Comment: @MikeM. you worked it out. Thanks very much - I didn't know the dialog wasn't blocking. Please paste this as the answer.

Comment: No problem! I don't really feel comfortable, however, posting an answer for an unfamiliar framework. :-) Please feel free to post an answer yourself. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments: The permissions dialog doesn't block, so in your first example, it's trying to request the camera permission immediately after showing the dialog for contacts. IIRC, that'll cause the second request to immediately return an empty result, and you aren't seeing anything from that. As I mentioned, I'm not familiar with React Native, but I'd guess that if you do the await in the contacts block, too, it'll work.